# Passing a blank / non-null VARIABLE in MYSQL Query (using Java)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So I am working on a small program in Java. Basically I want the user to search a database with one or 1-3 search query and they can use any combination.

A search query example would be: Book Name, ISBN, Author Name

The user can search with any combination (Search by book name only, or book name and author name, or all 3 etc...).

I want to basically write one master SQL statement (MYSQL), that would pull the results from the database. **The problem is, I don't know what to do with a blank input**.

So say user enters:

- Book name = Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
- ISBN = << left blank>>
- Author Name = JK Rowling

An example SQL query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM booklist
WHERE book_name = "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets"
AND ISBN = ""
AND Author = "JK Rowling";
```

In Java code I am using **PreparedStatement**, and the String would be:

```
String temp =  " SELECT * " + 
               " FROM booklist " + 
               " WHERE Title = " + title + 
               " AND Author = \"" + author + "\"" + 
               " AND ISBN = \"" + isbn + "\"";
```

Because the user did not enter ISBN, the SQL query fails (hence code fails). If I use **null** instead of **""**, then the query will still fail.

By fail meaning that it will not find the correct book in database (even though its present), as it is still looking for "" or null in the column.

Is there any way to pass kind of like a 'ghost' or invisible variable to get the SQL query to work like I am intending it to?

Or do I have to go the long way and make a SQL query for each possible combination?

Comment: You need to build your `WHERE` clause on-the-fly excluding columns that users leave blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR` instead of `AND`

**Change**:

```
String temp =  " SELECT * " + 
               " FROM booklist " + 
               " WHERE Title = " + title + 
               " AND Author = \"" + author + "\"" + 
               " AND ISBN = \"" + isbn + "\"";
```

**To**:

```
String temp =  " SELECT * FROM booklist " + 
               " WHERE Title = ? OR Author = ?" + 
               " OR ISBN = ?";
```

And then set the parameters for prepared statement.

```
pst.setString( 1, title );  
pst.setString( 2, author );
pst.setString( 3, isbn );
```

With the `OR` if any of the matching records are found then they are fetched.

And, if you still want to use `AND` for comparison and want to not include empty inputs then you have to dynamically prepare the statement in `JAVA`.

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder( 1024 );
sql.append( " SELECT * FROM booklist " );
String whereCondition = "";
if( title != null && title.trim().length() > 0 ) {
    whereCondition += " title = ?";
}
if( isbn != null && isbn.trim().length() > 0 ) {
    whereCondition += (whereCondition.length() > 0 ? " AND " : "" );
    whereCondition += " isbn = ?";
}
if( author != null && author.trim().length() > 0 ) {
    whereCondition += (whereCondition.length() > 0 ? " AND " : "" );
    whereCondition += " author = ?";
}

sql.append( " where " ).append( whereCondition );
pst = con.prepareStatement( sql.toString() );
```

Now set the prepared parameters like this:
And then set the parameters for prepared statement.

```
int paramIndex = 1;

if( title != null && title.trim().length() > 0 ) {
    pst.setString( paramIndex++, title );  
}
if( isbn != null && isbn.trim().length() > 0 ) {
    pst.setString( paramIndex++, isbn );  
}
if( author != null && author.trim().length() > 0 ) {
    pst.setString( paramIndex++, author );  
}
```

Now, you can execute the statement and fetch the resultset.

Comment: Thanks this is great! I totally understand what your doing. 

My only question is I dont understand your last block of code and what  your doing with the prepared statements? What is the purpose of doing pst.setString( paramIndex++, title )?

Comment: @user1861967: Using `PreparedStatement`, we can set query parameter values. It internally escapes any special characters in the values, that are not allowed, unless are escaped. And it also prevents SQL injection. And unless you `set...` values, they are not passed to database and execution would through an `SQLException`.